# Unexpected Moran's I value in R using a chessboard example

Tags: r, autocorrelation

I'm running into unexpected values for Moran's I when using the Moran.I function in the R library "ape".

My understanding is that a chessboard is an example of perfect negative spatial autocorrelation, which should yield a Moran's I value of -1.  But when I code a simple 8 x 8 grid, and give it a chessboard pattern, I get a value which, while negative, is not close to -1.

Consider this code:

```
library(ape)

# first, build an 8 x 8 grid
# lats and lngs will go from 0 to 7

lng <- rep(seq(0, 7, by=1), 8)

counter = 1
subCounter = 0
startNum = 0
lat = NULL

while (counter < 65) { 

    if (subCounter == 8) { 

        startNum = startNum + 1
        subCounter = 0

    }

    lat = c(lat, startNum)

    subCounter = subCounter + 1
    counter = counter + 1

}

# now add the black/ white chessboard pattern

chess <- rep(c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0), 4)

gridNum <- seq(1:64)

testGrid <- data.frame(gridNum, lat, lng, chess)

# simple Euclidean distance measure

testGrid.dists <- as.matrix(dist(cbind(testGrid$lng, testGrid$lat)))

# invert the distances, then replace the infinities with 0

testGrid.dists.inv <- 1 / testGrid.dists

diag(testGrid.dists.inv) <- 0

# now test the chessboard pattern

Moran.I(testGrid$chess, testGrid.dists.inv)
```

This yields the following values:

> $observed
>   [1] -0.07775248
>
> $expected
>   [1] -0.01587302
>
> $sd
>   [1] 0.01499786
>
> $p.value
>   [1] 3.693094e-05

The $observed value, while negative, is not the -1 I was anticipating.  Can anyone help?

Comment: You may want to have a look at this (http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66817/why-is-morans-i-not-equal-to-1-in-perfectly-dispersed-point-pattern)